# How to slice strings in a column by another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':['abcde','fghij','klmno','pqrst'], 'B':[1,2,3,4]})
```

I want to slice column A by column B  eg: `abcde[:1]=a, klmno[:3]=klm`
but two statements all failed：

```
df['new_column']=df.A.map(lambda x: x.str[:df.B])
df['new_column']=df.apply(lambda x: x.A[:x.B])
```

> TypeError: string indices must be integers

and

```
df['new_column']=df['A'].str[:df['B']]
```

`new_column` return `NaN`

Try to get `new_column`:

```
      A    B  new_column
0   abcde  1     a
1   fghij  2     fg
2   klmno  3     klm
3   pqrst  4     pqrs
```

Thank you so much

Answer (score 12):

You need `axis=1` in the [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method to loop through rows:

```
df['new_column'] = df.apply(lambda r: r.A[:r.B], axis=1)
df
#       A   B   new_column
#0  abcde   1   a
#1  fghij   2   fg
#2  klmno   3   klm
#3  pqrst   4   pqrs
```

---

A less idiomatic but usually faster solution is to use `zip`:

```
df['new_column'] = [A[:B] for A, B in zip(df.A, df.B)]
df

#       A   B   new_column
#0  abcde   1   a
#1  fghij   2   fg
#2  klmno   3   klm
#3  pqrst   4   pqrs
```

---

```
%timeit df.apply(lambda r: r.A[:r.B], axis=1)
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 440 µs per loop

%timeit [A[:B] for A, B in zip(df.A, df.B)]
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 27.6 µs per loop
```

Comment: @asuschen Glad it helps!

Comment: Psidom, you are a genius! Just for the record, you can also specify start and stop indices using your technique.

`df['new_column'] = [A[B:C] for A, B, C in zip(df.A, df.start_index df.end_index)]`

Comment: Why is `zip()` so much faster?

Answer (score 3):

By using `zip`.May this solution is helpful for you.

[image]